# Azure Function startup error System.Private.CoreLib: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's')

Tags: azure, function

I see the following error when starting an Azure Function: System.Private.CoreLib: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's').

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a missing AppSetting on start-up.